# Are they going to make a 7th Star Wars movie?

Tags: star-wars

Are they going to make a 7th Star Wars movie? Disney bought Lucasfilm for $4.05 billion dollars and they said they where thinking about making it in 2015.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about commercial thinking of a company holding a sci-fi work.

Comment: And you kind of answered it in the question.  (Obviously you heard that somewhere; where?)

Comment: Another -1 because a simple google search would have revealed tons of links. Laziness on your part does not mandate effort on ours.

Comment: Related [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/why-is-this-question-closed).

Answer (score 6):

Yes. They are going to make Episodes VII, VIII and IX. Disney did not buy the property to sit on it. They plan to make MANY movies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sequel_trilogy

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/combined

http://www.scified.com/news/1224

http://screenrant.com/star-wars-episodes-7-9-trilogy/

http://www.movieweb.com/news/george-lucas-spent-a-year-prepping-star-wars-episode-vii-before-it-went-to-disney

Disney has stated they plan to do *at least* one more trilogy with J.J. Abrams directing the first part, Episode VII, and they also plan to do some stand-alone films.